# How to prevent fckeditor to resize in Chrome browser?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, fckeditor

I have use fckeditor in asp.net. When user open the page containing fckeditor in Chrome. User can resize the text area of fckeditor. I want to prevent this.i.e.user should un-enable to resize the text area.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the specifics of fckeditor but usually you would need to add the following to your css:

```
textarea {resize: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option for disabling the resizing feature of editor: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.resize_enabled

But, Chrome adds its own resizing feature to all textareas, so to disable this, use Phil's suggestion.

Comment: But in which file i have to set resize: none ??? Not getting any solution to prevent resizing or fckeditor's text area. Please help.

Comment: In a CSS file or in html: `<head><style> textarea {resize: none} </style> ...`